# Unit testing a REST-Service

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest, jetty

I have a REST-Service based on the [spark-framework](http://sparkjava.com/). Looks like this(simplyfied):

```
public void init() {

    get(new Route("spark/favorites") {
        @Override
        public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
            ExternalService exS= new ExternalService();             

            ArrayList<String> favs= exS.getFavorites();

            Gson gson = getGson();
            return gson.toJson(favs);
        }
    });
 }
```

Now I want to write some tests for my service to see if my get/post/put/delete does what I want. 
Therefor I deploy it on an embedded Jetty during my tests.

The problem I a facing now is that my service depends on external REST-Services. I would like to mock all calls to those (to have a fast unit test). But I have no idea how to mock inside the running service.

Is that even possible? Should I switch to another REST-Framework?
Suggestions?

Comment: Please add the production code you use to access the third party REST services. Only then will we be able to suggest ways to mock these.

Comment: I want to mock classes like the ExternalService class.

Comment: It's not a unit test if you rely on Jetty being up. That's an integration test.

Comment: For me integrationtests include interactions with other components which is what I do not want therefor the mocking. If you know a way to test a spark class without jetty I am happy with that? I d prefer to do it without jetty. but sofar its the only way I know to access the REST routes offered by spark.

Comment: I don't think you should switch to another framework JUST because it's easier to Unit Test...

Answer (score 0):

that's an integration test, no matter if your app talks to webservice mocks or real 3rd party webservices. Unit test are when you test your classes in isolation.

If you want to mock out external webservices you would need to make links to 3rd party apps configurable and have a separate configuration just for integration testing.
For webservice mocking you could use one of several available mocking frameworks:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/soaprest-mocker